# MacBook Pro 2015 with 2013 Logic Board Boot Camp Error

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, hardware

Attempting to use Windows on my Mac using Boot Camp. I upgraded my Mac's storage. Using 1 TB of space: 600 GB for macOS, 400 GB for Windows, only to get the same error message of "Your device ran into a problem and needs to restart" which loops infinitely.

When I spoke to Apple Support they seem entirely dumbfounded. My Mac is a late 2015 model, but a computer repair shop replaced my logic board with one from 2013, so it's hard for others to really identify the issue.

- macOS Big Sur
- Processor 2.4 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5
- 8 GB Ram 1600 MHz DDR3
- Graphics: Intel Iris 1536 MB

Any troubleshooting advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you use the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows? Which Windows version? Did installation of Windows require a flash drive? Your question states three events: 1) Installing Windows. 2) Upgrading to 1 TB of storage. 3) Replacing the logic board. What order did these events occur?

Comment: I used bootcamp assistant to install Windows 10 Home and yes it required a flash drive.    I recently upgraded my ssd, and then after 'installed' windows, but my logic board was replaced years ago if that helps.